# Addition and Subtraction in C using fscanf()

Tags: c, function, loops

I have a text file with *n* lines of *m* length (it doesn't matter in the long term ). In every line, there is a sequence like this:

```
1 + 2 + 5 - 3 =
```

I'm using `fscanf` function to catch all numbers and operators and calculate it and when '=' operator found it prints into a different file. I'm using a loop . My question is how does C recognizes a number and operator? I know the operator is a type of `%c` and the number is of type `%d`, but how my program does work properly and why it doesn't take them for example 5 as a character :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   FILE *InFile;
   FILE *OutFile;
   int number=0;
   int result=0;
   char operator;
   int foundEqualsOp=0;
   InFile = fopen("dane.txt","r");
   OutFile = fopen("wynik.txt","w");
   while(fscanf(InFile,"%d",&result)!=EOF)
   {
        number = 0;
        foundEqualsOp = 0;
        while(!foundEqualsOP){

            fscanf(InFile,"%c",&operator);
            if(operator == '='){
                foundEqualsOp = 1;
                fprintf(OutFile,"%d\n",result);
            }
            else if(operator == '-'){
                fscanf(InFile,"%d",&number);
                result = result-number;
            }
            else if (operator == '+'){
                fscanf(InFile,"%d",&number);
                result = result + number;
            }
        }
  }
 fclose(InFile);
 fclose(OutFile);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't post screenshots here, prefer pasting a correctly formatted code, see [mcve].

Comment: Every time someone posts a picture of code on this site a kitten dies. Don't kill kittens. Copy, paste, and properly format/indent your code for presentation.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Is it really easier to make a screen copy, trim it and paste the image, rather than copy/pasting your code as text?

Comment: C doesn't recognize anything. You _code_ does it, or at least should do it.

Comment: If you pass the input string `1 + 2 5`, you will see that it will read `5` into `%c`  The only reason your current code isn't reading the `5` as a `%c` is that it never sees `5` as the next character in the stream when it is scanning it using the `%c` format string.

Comment: I retyped your code and it works as expected. What is the problem and what is the question ?

Comment: why does the fscanf() reads only the operators with '%c' as an agrument, but not numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume your input file contains the following as in your example:

```
1 + 2 + 5 - 3 =
```

The outer `scanf` reads with `%d`.  This picks up `1` as the integer value 1 and puts it in `result`.

Now the inner `scanf` runs with `%c`.  It reads the space after `1` so none of the `if` blocks are entered and the inner loop runs again.  The inner `scanf` again reads with `%c` and reads the `+` character.  This causes the `if (operator == '+')` block to be entered where a call to `scanf` uses `%d`.  This format specifier skips over the space after the `+` and reads `2` as the integer value 2 and adds it to `result`.

The above happens again reading the space after `2`, the `+` that follows, and the space and `5` that follows.  And again for the following space, `-`, space, and `3`.

After that, the `scanf` in the inner loop reads the space after `3` and does nothing, then on the next iteration it reads the `=` after which it prints the result and sets the flag to exit the inner loop.,